# how to pass returned values of a function in parent to its child component in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a function where I am getting currentMonth and date and the method returns it as below.

```
getDayMonth() {
return {
currentMonth: new Date().getMonth(),
currentDate: new Date().getDate()
  }
 }
```

The parent render() is a container and hence it should display the child component.

In my child component, I am trying to check the current date and month to load a specific image file as below

```
render() {
      return (

        <div className="childclass">
            {(this.props.currentMonth === 11 && this.props.currentDate >= 14 
                  && this.props.currentDate < 28) ?
                <img className="santa" src="../../img/spinny-santa.gif" /> : 
          <div className="progress-circle progress-indeterminate" />}

           </div>

           ) }
```

I have tried so many ways to access the currentDate/month. However, it shows undefined values.

Can some guide me as I am a beginner in reactjs?

Comment: Are you passing them to your child?

Comment: How you are passing them to child?

Comment: Yes I want to pass the values to my child component.
This is what I have now in my parent Render() method.

            getDayMonth ={this.getDayMonth}
            currentMonth={this.props.Date().currentMonth}
            currentDate={this.props.Date().currentDate}

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest breaking up the functions into two seperate functions. 
In your parent component, where you call your child, pass the dates as props.

```
export default class ParentComp extends React.Component {


<ChildContainer getDate={this.getDate} getMonth={this.getMonth} />

}
```

Then from your child container you can use the current date like this.

```
{this.props.getDate().bind(this)}
```

Here is an example from my code of passing a function to a child, then calling said function from the child to update the parent, where it came from...

From the parent

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        nickname: '', make: '', model: '', vehicleYear: '', vehicleMake: '', vehicleModel: '', toggleVehicleMake: false,
    }
    this.yearPicked = this.yearPicked.bind(this);
    this.makePicked = this.makePicked.bind(this);
    this.modelPicked = this.modelPicked.bind(this);
}

modelPicked(model) {
    this.setState({ vehicleModel: model }, function () {
        console.log(this.state, 'Updated Make')
    });
}

<VehicleModelPicker homeState={this.state} vehicleModel={this.modelPicked} />
```

From the Child

```
<Button block onPress={() => this.props.vehicleModel(this.state.selectedModel)}>
                            <Text>Done</Text>
                        </Button>
```

Comment: I added your input but now getting an error :this.props.getMonth is not a function.. Please advise as I am very new to this technology

Comment: I tried passing the currentDate and currentMonth to state of the parent and trying to access them from child.. When I tried to print the currentDate in console from child it gives me undefined value.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic class could look like this.

```
 import React from 'react';  
 import Child from './Child'

 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.getDayMonth = this.getDayMonth.bind(this);
  }

  getDayMonth() {
   return {
   currentMonth: new Date().getMonth(),
   currentDate: new Date().getDate()
   }
 }
 render(){
    return(
    <div>
    <Child getDayMonth={this.getDayMonth} />
    </div>
    )
 }
 }
```

Then the child could look like this. Notice how the getDayMonth function is bound to "this" in the constructor and passed as an argument/props to the child. The getDayMonth function can then be accessed on the props of the child. But... This is only one pattern, which is why others are asking how are you passing the function to the child.

```
 const Child = (props) =>{
 render() {
  return (
    <div className="childclass">
        {(props.getDayMonth.currentMonth === 11 && 
          props.getDayMonth.currentDate >= 14 
              && props.getDayMonth.currentDate < 28) ?
            <img className="santa" src="../../img/spinny-santa.gif" /> : 
      <div className="progress-circle progress-indeterminate" />}

       </div>

       ) }

  }
```

Comment: i am not sure if I implemented it correctly and having a constant just before render gives compile tie error and if I move it onside getting: A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object." error :(